# How specific is "the place where one ate"?

Tags: halacha, bentching

One is supposed to say birkat hamazon "in the place where he ate." How specific is this?
(the same building, the same room, the same table, or the same seat)

Answer (score 1):

The [Mishna Berura in 184:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.184.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that the same room is considered the same place even if you can't see the original place (i.e. a wedding hall) but if you have to be in a different room, then you need to be able to see the original place where you ate

> קודם שיעקור - ומפינה לפינה אפילו הבית גדול מותר ואפילו כשאין רואה מקומו הראשון כגון אחורי הפארא"וון וכיו"ב ואם היה לו מניעה שלא יוכל לברך בהחדר שאכל מותר לברך בחדר שסמוך לו אם יכול לראות מקומו שאכל ואם דעתו היה בשעת ברכת המוציא לברך בחדר אחר בבית זה אפשר דיש להקל בשעת הדחק [כגון שמקום שאכל אינו נקי לברך שם] אפילו אינו רואה מקומו הראשון:

As far as the same table vs the same seat, the Mishna Berura says 4 amos is the considered the same place

> ממקומו - וכל ד' אמות ממקום אכילתו חשיב מקום אחד ויוכל להעתיק ממקומו ע"י מניעה קטנה

Comment: What if less than 4 amot away is a place in a different room where you can't see the place you ate? This can happen in small apartments or shops or the like.

Comment: It can happen any place that a person ate right next to a door in a wall and now wants to bentch in the hallway outside. Wouldn't it be similiar to passing in front of someone davening that if there is a mechitza, even within 4 amos is permissible since it is a different reshus? Mishna Berura 102:2

Comment: I haven't a clue if it's similar.

Comment: I don't understand. He says the same room is the same place, and then he says within four _amos_ is the same place? Which is it? Like, what if he's more than four _amos_ away but in the same room: is that the same place or not?

Comment: @msh10 within 4 amis is even for a small reason, within the same room is only for a good reason